# Using "how" preceded by "of"

Tags: word-usage

This is the sentence that is confusing me:

> Thanks to this screenshot we have a better view [of how] this model is built.

In my language it is correct to use something like **"of how"** to introduce an explanation. But I'm not sure about using that in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is grammatical in English. Think of *how* as meaning ‘the way in which’.